# Can't get jquery cookie plugin to work

Tags: jquery, cookies

html:

```
<form id="testform">
<p><input type="text" name="one"></p>
</form>
```

js:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[name="one"]').change(function(){
        $.cookie("one", $('input[name="one"]').val(), {expires: 7});
    });
});
```

Yet when I close the browser and open it the value is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value of your input on page load:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[name="one"]').val($.cookie('one'))

    $('input[name="one"]').change(function(){
        $.cookie("one", $('input[name="one"]').val(), {expires: 7});
    });
});
```